# Ring homomorphism and characteristic

Tags: ring-theory

Let $F$ be a finite field. If $f : F \to F$, given by $ f(x) = x^3$ is a ring homomorphism, then

1. $ F = \mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{3Z}$
2. $ F = \mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{3Z}$ or  $ F = \mathbb{Z}/  \mathbb{2Z}$
3. $ F = \mathbb{Z}/  \mathbb{2Z}$ or characteristic of $F$ is 3.
4. Characteristic of $F$ is $3$

For ring homomorphism, $f(x+y)= f(x)+ f(y)$ and $f(xy)= f(x) f(y)$ for $x,y \in F$. So, Charcteristic of $F$ must be 3 so that $ 3x^2y + 3xy^2= 0$, so $4$ option should be true but how to discard option 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z)[x]/(x^2+1)$. It is a field $\not=\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ of characteristic $3$, so option $(1)$ is not true.

---

Similarly option $(2)$ is not a necessary condition for $x\mapsto x^3$ to be a ring homomorphism.

---

For option $(3)$, we shall show that it is necessary for $x\mapsto x^3$ to be a ring homomorphism that either $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ or $F$ has characteristic $3$.

By the binomial expansion, $x\mapsto x^3$ is a ring homomorphism if and only if $3(x^2y+xy^2)=0,\,\forall x, y\in F$. And this is true if and only if $3=0$ or $x^2y+xy^2=0$ in $F$.

The first case means $F$ has characteristic $3$.

The second case says that, when $x,y\not=0$, $xy$ is invertible, and hence $x+y=0$. This means that every non-zero element in $F$ is the additive inverse of $1_F$. As a consequence, there is only one non-zero element in $F$, i.e. $F=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$.

Thus option $(3)$ is a necessary condition.

---

Since $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has characteristic $2$, option $(4)$ is not necessary.

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: As an added bonus, if the characteristic of $F$ is $3$, the map $x\mapsto x^3$ is a generator for the (cyclic) Galois group of $F$ over $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$. It's called the Froebenius morphism (the same is true for other primes as well).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: What do you mean by 3=0? (What I understand by 3x in a ring is x+x+x.

Comment: @Gitika $x+x+x=(1+1+1)\cdot x=3\cdot x$. So $3(x^2y+xy^2)=0$ if and only if $3=0$ or $x^2y+xy^2=0$.

Comment: If every non-zero element in F is additive inverse of 1, then how does it imply that there is only one non-zero element in F?

Comment: @Gitika In a group the inverse of an element is unique. Since a field under addition forms a group, the additive inverse of $1_F$ is unique, so there is only one non-zero element in $F$.

Comment: How to show that in a and d, ring homomorphism will be there between the fields?

Comment: @Gitika The function $x\mapsto x^3$ from $F$ to $F$ is a homomorphism if and only if the characteristic of $F$ is $3$. To see this, expand $(x+y)^3$ and see it is equal to $x^3+y^3$.

Comment: You proved it for $\Bbb{Z_2}$ which has characteristic 2..right?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I didn't think clearly about it. I meant to say that when the characteristic of a field is $3$, then $x\mapsto x^3$ is a ring homomorphism, without the other direction (only if).